# Function not defined when using promises inside AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

**Context**

I'm trying to load in the like count of messages received from my database. I do this by executing an AJAX call that works fine and obtains the messages from the database, like so:

```
function getThreads() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/index/getForums.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item) {

                if (item.error == undefined) { //if not empty

                    let newContent =
                    //insert content here (I removed it for simplicity's sake)

                    let appended = $(newContent).appendTo(".threadsContainer");

                    ///start of the code in question
                    var forumId = $(appended).find(".forum_id").val();
                    var idUsers = $(appended).find(".idUsers").val();

                    var checkLike = checkLike(idUsers, forumId);
                    checkLike.done(function(data) {

                        console.log(data);

                    });
                    //end of the code in question

                }

            });
        }
    });

}
```

After receiving the messages from the database, I want to check the like count of each message, so I include a promise:

```
var checkLike = checkLike(idUsers, forumId);
checkLike.done(function(data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

The function `checkLike` is as follows:

```
function checkLike(idUsers, forumId) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/replyThread/checkLike.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {idUsers: idUsers, forumId: forumId}
    });

}
```

**Problem**

My problem is that, instead of logging the data, I get an error message that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: checkLike is not a function
```

**Question**

How can I alter this code so that the function is considered as a function? I've used similar code on other pages on the same website and they have worked fine. I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple or if I lack an understanding somewhere. Any ideas? Let me know if there's any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you be trying to define both a function and a variable both with the same name?  There's only one namespace so your two attempts at using the same name conflict with each other.  Don't do that and you won't have problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution - I just changed the name of the variable that calls the `checkLike` function to `var checkLikeCount = checkLike();` instead of `var checkLike = checkLike();`. This might be the solution to this sort of problem.

Comment: Would be interesting to read the standard to understand exactly what's going on. My guess is that the code to the left of the equal sign ( `var checkLike`) reassigned the value `undefined` to `checkLike`, and the code to the right of the equal sign executes after the assignment has completed.